# No recorre el Array JAVA

Tags: java

Tengo un problema tengo un array que quiero recorrer pero no se ejecuta el for.

```
String value = "val1\nval2";
String [] array = value.split("\n");
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    jlabel.setText(((i/array.length)*100)+"%");
}
```

No dice error pero tampoco sale el texto.

clare a aclarar que el valor de value es un archivo.txt

Comment: Si se recorre, el problema es la operaciòn que se realiza cuando los valores son de tipo int, cambia el valor de i a double, agreguè una respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `for` si se ejecuta, lo que sucede es que siempre obtendràs valores iguales a 0.

al obtener el array puedes iterar para poder mostrar los valores pero estas operaciones que realizas obtendrán valores enteros que serán redondeados a 0, al realizar la operaciòn siempre estaras obteniendo el valor de 0:

Operaciòn 1: `(0/2)*100) = 0`

Operaciòn 2: `(1/2)*100) = 0`

Para evitar el problema, si deseas obtener valores puedes definir el valor de `i` como `double` en tu `for`, de esta forma no se redondeara el valor y obtendràs valores diferentes a 0:

```
String value = "val1\nval2";
String [] array = value.split("\n");

for(double i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    jlabel.setText(((i/array.length)*100)+"%");
}
```

Comment: Gracias, Me ayudo mucho.

Comment: Excelente @gabriel , saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El bucle `for` se ejecuta perfectamente

```
public class TestSplit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String value = "val1\nval2";
        String [] array = value.split("\n");
        
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            String percentage = ((i/array.length)*100)+"%";
            System.out.println(array[i] + " " + percentage);
        }
    }

}
```

Salida

```
val1 0%
val2 0%
```

No está claro qué quieres conseguir exactamente ni como está construida tu aplicación Swing. Si añades un [ejemplo mínimo reproducible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) te podríamos ayudar mejor.

Por otro lado, suponiendo que se refrescara correctamente el contenido del `JLabel`, al no añadir ningún tipo de retardo tras invocar `setText`, lo más probable es que solo consigas el valor de la última iteración del bucle, no aparecerá nunca por pantalla una progresión de porcentajes.

En [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15199220/2553194) de Stack Overflow tienes un ejemplo de cómo implementar una barra de progreso con Java Swing, por si te sirve de inspiración o está relacionado con lo que quieres hacer.